# Return pipeline score as one of multiple evaluation metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search, scoring

I am using a pipeline in a hyperparameter gridsearch in sklearn. I would like the search to return multiple evaluation scores - one a custom scoring function that I wrote, and the other the default score function of the pipeline.

I tried using the parameter `scoring={'pipe_score': make_scorer(pipe.score), 'my_score' : my_scoring_func}` in my `GridSearchCV` instance (`pipe` is the name of my pipeline variable) but this returns `nan` for `pipe_score`.

What is a correct way to do this?

Comment: Always when getting NaN scores from a search, set the parameter `error_score="raise"` to get an error traceback to debug.

Comment: Probably you need to skip the `make_scorer` convenience function: `score` is already a scorer, not a metric.

Comment: ...but even then, it probably won't use the fitted cloned models...hm.

Comment: I'm not sure what the last comment meant, but it's not a scorer in that it takes `Y,Y_pred` rather than `estimator,X,,Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this by just using `None` as the value in the dict:

```py
scoring = {
    'pipe_score': None,
    'my_score': my_scoring_func,
}
```

---

To address your attempts a bit more (moving from comments):

Always when debugging `NaN` scores in a hyperparameter search, set `error_score="raise"` so that you get the error traceback.

`make_scorer` takes a *metric* with signature `(y_true, y_pred)` and turns it into a *scorer* with signature `(estimator, X_test, y_test)`.  Since `pipe.score` is already a scorer (with `self` as the estimator), you don't need this convenience function.

That won't fix things though: `pipe.score` is the method of the *instance* `pipe`, and so in the search you'll be trying to call it with the same instance of `pipe`, not the fitted versions that are being created during the search: you'll get all the same scores, or an error.